# Meta-data tags with React Helmet and React Snapshot

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, jsdom

I need to add somes meta tags to my react app , for this I am using react helmet to edit the head of my website and react-snapshot for pre-render the website static .
When react-snapshot try to build the app I am facing this error

Error: Not implemented: HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext (without installing the canvas npm package)

I read so many topic about this issue and tried all of Thoses , install jest-canvas-mock , canvas-prebuilt .... no one worked for me .
Also , I am not using jest at all in my project , I uninstalled it from my project but didn’t help so I don’t understand why I am facing with this error

Comment: I assume you're seeing Jest-related things in your research because of [snapshot testing](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/snapshot-testing), but [`react-snapshot`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-snapshot) is doing something totally different.

Comment: Like I said I am not using jest and no needs to use it, react-snapshot use jest by default ?

Comment: I understand that, I'm explaining why you might see search results relating to Jest.